# Thesis 1.8 / Wordpress 3.3.1 Error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /wp-content/themes/thesis_18/lib/classes/css.php on line 60

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I was just updating some sidebar widgets, a feature box, and one link color change in "Design Options" within the Thesis Theme when I started to get the following error:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /wp-content/themes/thesis_182/lib/classes/css.php on line 60

I have tried deactivating the theme and reactivating, ungrading to thesis 1.8.2  but the error keeps occurring. It looks like all the "design options" i had selected went back to the defaults and I can't even update any of them.

The web address for the property is http://realitychicblog.com

Comment: What is there on line 60? Where does the array (and it has to be an array) passed to the foreach get set?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. I had W3 Cache plugin installed and activated.

Once I emptied the browser cache I stopped having the issue.